# JAVA_HOME not setting for RJB

Tags: java-home, rjb

I am installing RJB by ruby gem on UBUNTU 11.*
I added the

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-...
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

to the `.bashrc` file at home directory. 
But still it throws the err or `JAVA_HOME` not set.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

`echo  $JAVA_HOME` shows exactly the right path.
And I did log on again, even reboot. But still throws the same error.

Comment: Exit from the session and then login again, then try. bashrc is executed on login.

Comment: run this command in terminal and see output `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: echo  $JAVA_HOME shows exactly the right path.
And I did log on again, even reboot. But still throws the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I've run the same issue in Ubuntu 10.04. What ended up working for me was to su into root and install:

```
sudo su -
export JAVA_HOME=/usr....
gem install rjb
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Apparantly, sudo is not taking all the environment further... thanks for ur tip..

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the variable continues to be available after reboot, you can create the following file:

`/etc/profile.d/javaenv.sh`

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk # <- make sure this path is correct
```

Now, once your server is rebooted, your `JAVA_HOME` variable will be available to all users.

If you want to enable it immediately, run:

```sh
sudo sh /etc/profile.d/javaenv.sh
```